Conjecture on all $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}/3^k\mathbb{Z}$ that the sum/difference/product of $m^a$ and $n^a$ equals $0$
It is well known that for any integers $n,m$ we have that one of the three $m+n$, $mn$ or $m-n$ is zero modulo $3$. This means, that in the finite field $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ we can always obtain the neutral element with respect to addition by using two elements and then (at least) one of the three operations will yield it.
I was wondering whether we can say something similar for $\mathbb{Z}/3^k\mathbb{Z}$ for $k>1$. Obviously, this does not extend directly, pick for example for $k=2$ the numbers $n=1$ and $m=2$ which give $n+m=3$, $n-m=8$ and $nm=2$ modulo $3^2$. None of the three are $0$.
So, I came to the following conjecture that for any pair $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}/3^k\mathbb{Z}$ we have
$$m^{3^{k-1}}+n^{3^{k-1}}=0\quad \text{ or }\quad m^{3^{k-1}}-n^{3^{k-1}}=0\quad\text{or}\quad m^{3^{k-1}}n^{3^{k-1}}=0.$$
I checked it computationally until $k=7$ using the simple python code
from itertools import product

b = 3
k = 7
l = b**(k-1)
test_list = [((i**l+j**l)%(b**k))*((i**l-j**l)%(b**k))*((i**l*j**l)%(b**k)) for i,j in product(range(b**k),range(b**k))]
print(sum(test_list))

but I do not find a general prove approach. For all cases where $m$ or $n$ are divisible by $3$ it is simple since then the factor $3^{3^{k-1}}$ is $0$ modulo $3^k$ and so the product $mn$ is $0$ modulo $3^k$.
Are there also other powers $a$ such that for all $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}/3^k\mathbb{Z}$
$$m^{a}+n^{a}=0\quad \text{ or }\quad m^{a}-n^{a}=0\quad\text{or}\quad m^{a}n^{a}=0?$$
Is this already known or does anyone have an idea how to approach a proof/counterexample?

You seem to be confusing $GF(3^k)$ with $\mathbb Z/3^k \mathbb Z$. The latter is numbers modulo $3^k$ and is never a field (if $k>1$), while the former contains elements that are not numbers.

@lisyarus Indeed, I will change it to the ring $\mathbb{Z}/3^k\mathbb{Z}$.

@xxxxxxxxx Thank you, I will try and give my results here.

Yes, this will always work because these are effectively approximations of the Teichmuller characters in the $3$-adics. This is similar to Hensel lifting if you're familiar with that - with each power we're effectively getting closer to $0$, $1$, or $-1$ as an approximation to the $3$-adic limits,
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} m^{3^k}.$$
Putting any $p$-adic jargon aside, it's sufficient to do an induction argument. Fix $a \in A = \{0,1,-1\}$ and then show there exists an integer $b_k$ at each step of the way. This follows from a binomial expansion and the fact the elements of $A$ are fixed by raising to the third power:
$$(a+3^kb_k)^3 = a+3^{k+1}b_{k+1}$$
Please don't hesitate to let me know in the comments if you need more details to complete the argument or if you have any questions!
